# Google analytics - do exceptions stop session?

Tags: http, session, exception, google-analytics, universal-analytics

I use google analytics to track user behaviour in an application. What I do is this:

- Send a [start session](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#sc)
- Send a custom [event](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#events) "Lifetime start"
- If there is an error: send a [fatal exception](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#exception)
- Send a custom [event](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#events) "Lifetime stop"
- Send a [stop session](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#sc)

Now when I look at the statistics, I see that a certain percentage of users had an exception over tha last 30 days. However, **all users have had sessions without exception!**. This is almost impossible, since I know there are users where the application crashes every time.

**Is it possible that the `fatal exception` I submit terminates the session?** So even users where the app crashes everytime get a second (short) session, containing only the "Lifetime stop" custom event? (That would explain my statistics)

Comment: Can you still send data to GA after the crash..? (Belonging to the same session, that is)

Comment: That's what I'm trying to do, but my question is exactly if this will work ;)

Comment: Hm, now idk if there something like beforeUnload equiv in your app, but maybe you'd be better off checking for people w/ timed out sessions vs. manual exits?

Answer (score 0):

That being said, I ran a test using Universal Analytics via the web (so this was not done in an app), but the results should be consistent with your setup.

I started a session and sent a "Before Exception" event which showed up in my real-time event report. I then waited a few seconds and successfully sent a fatal exception (which there is not a real-time report for). Without refreshing I then sent an "After Exception" event which came through fine in my real-time report.

From the following screenshot (User Explorer), you can see the two "Exception Test" events that I described both in the same session.

[image: Events appear]

I would think that whatever fatal crash you're seeing is what is preventing additional data from appearing in Google Analytics- not that Google Analytics is ending the session at the time of the fatal exception. If it was ending the session, you'd still see events for "Lifetime stop", but it sounds like you aren't seeing those events at all.

The only things that end a GA session:

- Session timeout (default: 30 minutes)
- End of day
- UTM/AdWords/Referral
- Manually ending the session as you described

You may need to come up with some context clues to actually get to the bottom of this (maybe a remote server log?), but from the information provided (and if I'm understanding it correctly) I'm leaning towards the crash preventing the rest of the code from running.

Comment: Thanks for your tests! But that's the thing, I do get the lifetime stop events. But it seems that a second session is started with only the lifetime stop event, instead of only one session which includes the lifetime start, the lifetime stop and the exception...

Comment: That is interesting. I'm certain that the exception will not cause the session to end in Google Analytics, so I still stand by my hunch that there must be something else causing the end of the session.

Comment: So in your example, you can see in the analytics that all sessions recorded contain an exception? And the number of sessions is exactly the number of tests you ran?

Comment: That's correct- I only ran one test, but I can see that session contained all pageviews, events (including before and after the exception) and the exception itself. Have you checked out the User Explorer on yours? It probably is the best visualization for individual sessions (however they don't show the exceptions... at least for web-based analytics). Again, I know app analytics is slightly different (I think you have an "Exceptions and Crashes" report whereas I need to make a custom report for it), but that should not change how sessions are handled within GA tracking itself.

Comment: Actually I was using the web based analytics in our project, not the app SDK. Anyway, I can't debug it anymore, unfortunately, as I'm not working on that part of the project anymore. Thanks for your help and tests anyway!